# "Illegal instance declaration" when declaring instance of IsString

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm writing an application that uses UTF-16 strings, and to make use of the overloaded strings extension I tried to make an `IsString` instance for it:

```
import Data.Word ( Word16 )
import Data.String ( IsString(fromString) )

type String16 = [Word16]

instance IsString [Word16] where
    fromString = encodeUTF16

encodeUTF16 :: String -> String16
```

The problem is, when I try to compile the module, GHC 7.0.3 complains:

```
Data/String16.hs:35:10:
    Illegal instance declaration for `IsString [Word16]'
      (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
       where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
       and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
       Use -XFlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    In the instance declaration for `IsString [Word16]'
```

If I comment out the instance declaration, it compiles successfully.

Why is this rejected? The instance for `[Char]` looks pretty much like the same thing, yet it compiles fine. Is there something I've missed?

Comment: You should consider using [text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text), which uses UTF-16 internally. Or at least a newtype wrapper around `[Word16]`, to avoid problems and conflicts of this sort.

Comment: @ehird Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to implement Java's string hashing function which works on 16-bit characters. Unfortunately, the text package doesn't have an easy way of working on the raw Word16 without resorting to dark magic.

Comment: If you import [Data.Text.Internal](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.1.12/doc/html/Data-Text-Internal.html), you can access the underlying [Array](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.1.12/doc/html/Data-Text-Array.html).

Comment: Well, `case s of { Text array offs len -> A.toList array offs len }` isn't too bad :)

Comment: You could also [encode it into a UTF-16 ByteString](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.1.12/doc/html/Data-Text-Encoding.html#v:encodeUTF16LE), but that probably won't help you. Anyway, I'd definitely suggest a `newtype` around the list at the very least.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

After having a look through the GHC manuals and around the Haskell wiki (especially the [List instance](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_instance) page), I've got a better idea of how this works. Here's a summary of what I've learned:

#### Problem

The [Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-770004.3.2) defines an instance declaration like this:

> The type (*T u<sub>1</sub> … u<sub>k</sub>*) must take the form of **a type constructor *T* applied to simple type variables *u<sub>1</sub>, … u<sub>k</sub>***; furthermore, **T must not be a type synonym**, and the u<sub>i</sub> must all be distinct.

The parts highlighted in bold are the restrictions that tripped me up. In English, they are:

1. Anything after the type constructor *must* be a type variable.
2. You can't use a type alias (using the `type` keyword) to get around rule 1.

So how does this relate to my problem?

`[Word16]` is just another way of writing `[] Word16`. In other words, `[]` is the constructor and `Word16` is its argument.

So if we try to write:

```
instance IsString [Word16]
```

which is the same as

```
instance IsString ([] Word16) where ...
```

it won't work, because it violates rule 1, as the compiler kindly points out.

Trying to hide it in a type synonym with

```
type String16 = [Word16]
instance IsString String16 where ...
```

won't work either, because it violates part 2.

So as it stands, it is impossible to get `[Word16]` (or a list of *anything*, for that matter) to implement `IsString` in standard Haskell.

Enter... (drumroll please)

#### Solution #1: `newtype`

The solution @ehird suggested is to wrap it in a `newtype`:

```
newtype String16 = String16 { unString16 :: [Word16] }
instance IsString String16 where ...
```

It gets around the restrictions because `String16` is no longer an alias, it's a new type (excuse the pun)! The only downside to this is we then have to wrap and unwrap it manually, which is annoying.

#### Solution #2: Flexible instances

At the expense of portability, we can drop the restriction altogether with flexible instances:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

instance IsString [Word16] where ...
```

This was the solution @[Daniel Wagner] suggested.

#### Solution #3: Equality constraints

Finally, there's an even less portable solution using equality constraints:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

instance (a ~ Word16) => IsString [a] where ...
```

This works better with type inference, but is more likely to overlap. See [Chris Done's article on the topic](https://chrisdone.com/posts/haskell-constraint-trick/).

(By the way, I ended up making a `foldl'` wrapper around [Data.Text.Internal](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.1.12/doc/html/Data-Text-Internal.html) and writing the hash on top of that.)

Answer (score -14):

> Why is this rejected?

Because:

```
  (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
   where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
   and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
```

> Is there something I've missed?

Yes:

```
   Use -XFlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
```

Comment: I'm sure anyone who would have run into this problem (including me yesterday) would have had no idea what "flexible instances" were. Can you please expand on what that means?

Comment: `FlexibleInstances` just relaxes the restriction @DanielWagner quoted; the GHC manual [has more information](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-decls) on the alternate restrictions used instead. [This](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/FlexibleInstances) might help you too.