# Make Lenses (TH) with the Same Field Name using makeClassy

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, haskell-lens

> This question is regarding Edward A. Kmett's [lens package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13) (version 4.13)

I have a number of different `data` types all of which have a field that denotes the maximum number of elements contained (a business rule subject to run time change, not a collection implementation issue.) I would like to call this field `capacity` in all cases, but I quickly run into namespace conflicts.

I see in the `lens` documentation that there is a `makeClassy` template, but I cannot find documentation for it that I con understand.  Will this template function allow me to have multiple lenses with the same field name?

---

**EDITED**:
Let me add that I am quite capable of coding *around* the problem.  I would like to know if `makeClassy` will *solve* the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the documentation a bit unclear too; had to figure out what the various things Control.Lens.TH did by experimentation.

What you want is `makeFields`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies
           , MultiParamTypeClasses
           , TemplateHaskell
  #-}

module Foo
where

import Control.Lens

data Foo
  = Foo { fooCapacity :: Int }
  deriving (Eq, Show)
$(makeFields ''Foo)

data Bar
  = Bar { barCapacity :: Double }
  deriving (Eq, Show)
$(makeFields ''Bar)
```

Then in ghci:

```
*Foo
λ let f = Foo 3
|     b = Bar 7
| 
b :: Bar
f :: Foo

*Foo
λ fooCapacity f
3
it :: Int

*Foo
λ barCapacity b
7.0
it :: Double

*Foo
λ f ^. capacity
3
it :: Int

*Foo
λ b ^. capacity
7.0
it :: Double

λ :info HasCapacity 
class HasCapacity s a | s -> a where
  capacity :: Lens' s a
    -- Defined at Foo.hs:14:3
instance HasCapacity Foo Int -- Defined at Foo.hs:14:3
instance HasCapacity Bar Double -- Defined at Foo.hs:19:3
```

So what it's actually done is declared a class `HasCapacity s a`, where capacity is a `Lens'` from `s` to `a` (`a` is fixed once `s` is known). It figured out the name `capacity` by stripping off the (lowercased) name of the data type from the field; I find it pleasant not to have to use an underscore on either the field name or the lens name, since sometimes record syntax is actually what you want. You can use `makeFieldsWith` and the various `lensRules` to have some different options for calculating the lens names.

In case it helps, using `ghci -ddump-splices Foo.hs`:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Foo              ( Foo.hs, interpreted )
Foo.hs:14:3-18: Splicing declarations
    makeFields ''Foo
  ======>
    class HasCapacity s a | s -> a where
      capacity :: Lens' s a
    instance HasCapacity Foo Int where
      {-# INLINE capacity #-}
      capacity = iso (\ (Foo x_a7fG) -> x_a7fG) Foo
Foo.hs:19:3-18: Splicing declarations
    makeFields ''Bar
  ======>
    instance HasCapacity Bar Double where
      {-# INLINE capacity #-}
      capacity = iso (\ (Bar x_a7ne) -> x_a7ne) Bar
Ok, modules loaded: Foo.
```

So the first splice made the class `HasCapacity` and added an instance for `Foo`; the second used the existing class and made an instance for `Bar`.

This also works if you import the `HasCapacity` class from another module; `makeFields` can add more instances to the existing class and spread your types out across multiple modules. But if you use it again in another module where you *haven't* imported the class, it'll make a *new* class (with the same name), and you'll have two separate overloaded `capacity` lenses that are not compatible.

---

`makeClassy` is a bit different. If I had:

```
data Foo
  = Foo { _capacity :: Int }
  deriving (Eq, Show)
$(makeClassy ''Foo)
```

(noticing that `makeClassy` prefers you to have an underscore prefix on the fields, rather than the data type name)

Then, again using `-ddump-splices`:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Foo              ( Foo.hs, interpreted )
Foo.hs:14:3-18: Splicing declarations
    makeClassy ''Foo
  ======>
    class HasFoo c_a85j where
      foo :: Lens' c_a85j Foo
      capacity :: Lens' c_a85j Int
      {-# INLINE capacity #-}
      capacity = (.) foo capacity
    instance HasFoo Foo where
      {-# INLINE capacity #-}
      foo = id
      capacity = iso (\ (Foo x_a85k) -> x_a85k) Foo
Ok, modules loaded: Foo.
```

The class it's created is `HasFoo`, rather than `HasCapacity`; it's saying that anything from anything where you can get a Foo you can also get the capacity of the `Foo`. And the *class* hard-codes that the `capacity` is an `Int`, rather than overloading it as you had with `makeFields`. So this still works (because `HasFoo Foo`, where you just get the `Foo` by using `id`):

```
*Foo
λ let f = Foo 3
| 
f :: Foo

*Foo
λ f ^. capacity
3
it :: Int
```

But you can't use this `capacity` lens to also get the capacity of an unrelated type.

Answer (score 1):

The templates are optional; you can always make your own classes and lenses.

```
class Capacitor s where
  capacitance :: Lens' s Int
```

Now any type with a capacity can be made an instance of this class.

---

An alternative approach is to factor out the capacity:

```
data Luggage a = Luggage { clothes :: a, capacity :: !Int }
```

Comment: Yep, I'm heading down that road, but it wouldn't be great if the template library would do that for me? Code I don't write is code I don't have to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the field name with an underscore and the data type name, then use `makeFields`:

```
data Structure = Structure { _structureCapacity :: Int }
makeFields ''Structure

data OtherStructure = OtherStructure { _otherStructureCapacity :: String }
makeFields ''Structure
```

Comment: `makeFields ''Structure` doesn't compile (even if you enable the `TypeSynonymInstances` extension). The reasons for this are outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8663534/1417275. I find this rather restricting since I can't use `makeFields` for any data types with higher order fields.