# Haskell: error while using custom type in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have declared the following type

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a,String)]
```

and some function to operate on the parser as the bellow

```
succeed :: a -> Parser a
succeed v = \inp -> [(v,inp)]
```

when trying to run `stack ghci` in order to test the above function `succeed` I got an error that Parser is not an instance of `show` so I've tried to update the code and add the following

```
instance Show Parser where
  show [(v,inp)] = show (v,inp)
```

but I got an error that `Show` is expecting the argument to be `*` but it is `* -> *`

How could I solve that so I can test my function in `GHCi`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, the short answer is: you cannot do this.

The long answer involves using a `newtype`:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser [(a, String)]

instance Show (Parser a) where
  ...
```

For an explanation, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633470/illegal-instance-declaration-when-declaring-instance-of-isstring) question.

Comment: I did but the compiler gave me `illegal instance declaration for 'Show (Parser a)'`

Comment: @Threex , I tried it without that piece of code and then run in ghci `succeed "test"` and I got an error that  Parser a is not an instance of show

Comment: it worked for me to encapsulate it in a new type as the following : `new type Parser a = Parser {parse :: String -> [(a,String)]}` but I got an error on the function succeed so how could I fix the `succeed` function to work with the new type

Comment: @khaledomar You have to construct the parser by using `\inp -> Parser [(v, inp)]`.

Answer (score 1):

Just Enter this in `GHCi`:

```
let succeed :: a -> String -> [(a, String)]; succeed v = \inp -> [(v, inp)]
```

test:

```
succeed 12 "str"
```

output:

```
[(12,"str")]
```

test:

```
Prelude> :t succeed
succeed :: a -> String -> [(a, String)]
```

---

Also this works in `GHCi`:

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a,String)]
let succeed :: a -> Parser a; succeed v = \inp -> [(v, inp)]
```

test:

```
succeed 12 "str"
```

output:

```
[(12,"str")]
```

test:

```
Prelude> :t succeed
succeed :: a -> Parser a
```

Comment: @khaled-omar  I hope this helps

Comment: it helps in GHCI but what  I wanted is to create the whole in an editor then  test my code in GHCI  since I have many other parser functions

Answer (score 1):

This is really not what you want, I don't think. The usual way to define a parser of this type is

```
newtype Parser a = Parser {runParser :: String -> [(a, String)]}
```

The parser itself is a *function* whose result is a list. You can't really show one very meaningfully. One option the other answers get at is to write a custom type for the parser result:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser {runParser :: String -> Result a}

newtype Result a = Result {getResult :: [(a, String)]}

instance Show a => Show (Result a) where
  show (Result xs) = case xs of
    [] ->  "No results"
    [x] -> "One result: " ++ show x
    _ -> "Multiple results"
```